# Is there any fastest way to make a string a numeric barcoded in crystal report? (used in c#.net)

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

Currently, I have created a crystal report and set the datasource of it to a datatable.
I want to print a string of numerics in barcode 39 style.

Previously, I managed to make it by installing a barcode39 font in the system and use the crystal report formula format the string to "*00000001*".

But, What I want is dynamic barcode generation without munually installing additional font.
I've found some good stuff on-line:

1) I download a .NET Barcode Generator from .NET barcodelib.com, add an reference to the file BarcodeLib.Barcode.dll and follow the guide to create a barcode object; but it does not work at all

2) I'm looking for a way to programmatically add a font path to the object as I have a class creating a code 39 font file

Hope my description is simple enough for understanding :)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

@Roy there is no straight way to optimize this, It is my suggestion that you should call your bar code generation method in a separate thread. In this way bar code will take time but your application will not halt.